# Show only the year (no century) for select dates in the X axis

Tags: string, date, d3.js, date-format

I'm showing only certain dates in my X axis and I'm selecting these dates from my "dataPop" array with the `tickValues` function:

```
xAxisPop.tickValues([dataPop[0].date, dataPop[20].date, dataPop[40].date])
```

however, I'd like `dataPop[20].date` and `dataPop[40].date` to only show the year and not the century, for example, 1980 as 80.

I have a variable "formatDate" written to show only the year and not century:

```
formatDate = d3.time.format("%y")
```

but how do I apply formatDate to `dataPop[20].date`, `dataPop[40].date` in the tickValues function?

Also, fyi. My dates are currently strings... so I suppose instead of using d3.time.format in my formatDate function I should be using a different D3 formatting method that formats strings...is that correct?  or should I be changing the dates from strings to dates first, and then running the formatDate function?

thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll pass the formatter in to `xAxisPop.tickFormat`.  Any d3 text formatting option like `tickFormat` takes a regular JavaScript function as a parameter.  `d3.time.format` is just a helper method to construct the common ones.

In your case, since your dates are just strings, I'd recommend just writing your own formatting function, perhaps:

```
function formatTwoDigitYear(d) { return d.substr(2,2); }
```

That being said, you'd probably see a number of advantages by converting the textual years to dates as early as you can.

Comment: Thanks so I have that formatTwoDigitYear function and then I've written:  xAxisPop.tickValues([dataPop[0].date, dataPop[20].date, dataPop[40].date]); 
xAxisPop.tickFormat(formatTwoDigitYear);  ...so now all of my dates in the X axis are two digits. However, I'd like dataPop[0].date and dataPop[40].date to go back to the old way of 4 digits and only for these two years.  Is there a way to do that?  BTW- I think I need to keep the dates as strings since I'm using .rangeroundbands for my X axis scale (which treats the X axis as categories, and not numbers/dates), since this is a bar chart.

Comment: Since the formatter is just a regular JavaScript function, you can add logic to it such as checking for the case of `dataPop[2].date`.  Something to the effect of `return d == dataPop[2].date ? formatTwoDigitYear(d) : formatFourDigitYear(d);`